# “Don’t throw the game, throw POKéBALLs instead!”?

Tags: terminology, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

The original Pokémon Red and Blue games feature a sign that says

> Don’t throw the game, throw POKéBALLs instead!

There’s a video of this sign on YouTube:

I have never understood what this sign means. Is this a piece of wordplay that’s going over my head? Is this something that got lost in translation?

Comment: My guess is its a wordplay on "don't rage quit and throw your Game Boy"

Answer (score 5):

To ["throw the game"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+the+game) means to lose on purpose, either through deliberate misplay or lack of preparation.

To ["throw POKéBALLs"](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball) is a core game mechanic of the series. It would be very difficult to win without doing it.

So yes, it is wordplay. Both in- (referring to competing in Pokémon battles) and out-of-Universe (referring to playing the GameBoy game).